# OPENCV: add a bigger rectangle to countour rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have this image
and with this code below I have obtained this https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cg2RcJlrr7b3Z9HazApLo-HYubw2F6M/view?usp=sharing

```
contours = cv2.findContours(gray.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 500:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)
        #cv2.drawContours(filled_after, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)
```

Now I would like to add a bigger rectangle from the left higher angle to the right lower angle which will contain close rectangles. This is my expected output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Cd8sE6SeY-kpiRnsafNSIOJWXs773L5/view?usp=sharing

I have already tried cv2.convexHull and it isn't what I want.

ORIGINAL IMAGE without any countour: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGFlW5gLmAi9o1FkevZZzZaDmhYfHKVo/view?usp=sharing

Could you help?

Comment: Your before and after images are not accessible

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear now it should be better

Comment: Do you want those two separate rectanges or would you like that to be detected as a single object?

Comment: Could you also post the original image (prior to any processing)

Comment: Yes! I have added it @SneakyPolarBear

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how close you want for two separated lines to become just one.

If it's so close like in the image, I think blurring the image a little bit before findContours would do the trick.

But if you expect to group two separated lines that are quite far from each other and blurring would not be enough, you are try looking for something like  `NMSBoxes` in cv2.dnn. You basically give all boxes you drew in the image and the method will try to group them if they are close enough according to your given threshold.

Comment: Hi! I don't want to merge two lines into one. I just want to have a bigger rectangle that enclose smaller rectangles that are close to each other.